# Within 300 km radius of Tokyo - Coastal/seaside destinations in Japan for nature and relaxation?

Tags: japan, nature-and-wildlife, tokyo, rural

Since I'm planning to visit Japan for 10 days and plan to apportion 5 days to Tokyo, I thought to reframe [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/31208/13759) inside a 300 km radius around Tokyo. 300 is just an estimate; I'm not strict about this. Moreover, I'm curious to know if where urban [Tokyoites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectivals_and_demonyms_for_cities) go, for want of a seaside/costal  region for picturesque, scenic relaxation, resembling that of a nature getaway/resort/retreat. I tried https://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/location/interests/index_th_10.html and

> such as it's written [in the last paragraph here](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294232-i525-k4273704-Need_seaside_town_suggestion_please-Japan.html), I equally want: 'We love rocky beaches, nature hikes, history, the smell of ocean air, the scenery of water, and ... to experience Japan in a smaller town way'

but I would like the satisfaction of these criteria:

1. I want to avoid bears and lethal animals.
2. Due to possible radiation, I'd like to shun Fukushima and its surroundings.
3. I won't drive, so must rely on public transport and walking (over reasonable distances).
4. I want to evade temples and all buildings related to religion.

Comment: How is this question different from http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31143/within-300-km-radius-of-tokyo-where-for-nature-flora-and-fauna/ ?

Comment: @LePressentiment You can edit your former question, there is no need to create another one with *nearly exactly* the same conditions. People coming later want to have the information in one piece, not scattered over several pieces.

Comment: @LePressentiment I looked at your account and you asked this very same question **five times** ?!

Comment: @jpatokal: I esteemed as different questions because the coast/sea shore does not imply nature, flora, and fauna. The converse implication also fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enoshima, Kamakura and Zushi are on the Shonan coast and reachable from central Tokyo in 90 minutes. Enoshima has direct express service from Shinjuku. Kamakura has the giant buddha but you can easily avoid both him and the very large temple at the north end of Kamakura. All have sandy beaches and bustling retail areas.

A bit further down the road is Odawara and Atami, both Shinkansen stops. Odawara is a bedroom community for Tokyo, Atami is a beach / spa town and rather less busy than the Shonan coast.

Even furthur south is Izu Kogen and Shimoda. Much easier to get there by car, rent something in Odawara.

Completely the other direction is the eastern Chiba coastline. Seaworld is in Kamogawa and has very nice beaches.

You won't find bears or poisonous snakes in Japan without considerable deliberate effort. Lots of monkeys around that will grab anything shiny or edible, and hawks will dive-bomb your beach picnic. Eat under a tent where they can't see it.

Non-beach relaxation can be found in Hakone, just up the hill from Odawara. And the Fuji 5 lakes district is popular in the summer as it's a lot cooler up there.

Answer (score 2):

Jogashima (城ヶ島), at the southern tip of the Miura peninsula, is a decent day trip. Rocky beaches, tidepools with marine life, and a nice hike along a bluff where you can see cormorants. There's a small town with eateries serving fresh seafood.

The Keikyu rail/bus network sells a one-day pass (I think weekend only) that will cover the train and bus fare from various points in Tokyo/Yokohama and allow you to get off anywhere along the way.

Another choice is to take the Tokyo Bay Ferry from Kurihama (also on the Keikyu line), to Kanaya in Chiba. And in your case, avoid the main attraction, Nokogiriyama (鋸山), which is a temple complex built on top of the cliff, and instead walk south along the coast as far as you please. The neighboring town of Hota is very quiet and typical of small seaside villages in the area.